# Storing dynamic array in vector

Tags: c++

I have to display a histogram of a student's grades. I've stored the grades in a dyn. array, but my goal is to store them in a vector. What's the right way of going about this? Hope this makes sense.

Edit:

My attempt at using a vector

```
void displayHistogram(int minGrade, vector<int> ptrV) {

cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i <= minGrade; i++) {
    if (ptrV[i] != 0) {
        cout << "Number of " << i << "'s: " << ptrV[i] << endl;
    }
}

}

void histogram() {

int minGrade = 0, grade;
const int grade_max = 100;
vector<int> ptrV(grade_max, 0);

cout << "Enter the student's grades (-1 to stop entering): \n";
do {
    cin >> grade;
    if (grade > minGrade) {
        minGrade = grade;
    }
    if (grade >= 0) {
        ptrV.push_back(grade);
    }
} while (grade != -1);

displayHistogram(minGrade, ptrV);

}
```

Comment: Does the code work now?  If so, have you tried changing `int *ptr;` to `std::vector<int> ptr;` and start from there?  If so, what issues and/or errors did you encounter?  (I need to ask, since this code review questions should go to [StackExchange code review])(https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: OT.: `do` `while()` is a bit unlucky in your case. Why not `while ((cin >> grade) && (grade >= 0))`?

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) can be used like an array and has a lot of additional options. Some of them are: can be initialized with a certain size and default values (sufficient for your case), can be initialized like an array, can grow after construction and so on. There are lots of docs and examples beyond the one given in the link and can be found by web search.

Comment: If you don't need the feature of growing after initialization, [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) might be another option. It provides a similar interface like `std::vector` (except for the dynamic resizing).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes it works perfectly find, although, I have to store the grades in a vector. I tried this, but when I try to fill the vector with the grades I get an runtime error.

Comment: @Scheff I believe it would need to grow because the user needs to enter as many grades as they require, correct?

Comment: @sethFrias ok, post that attempt also with the usage of vector, so that we have something to work with.

Comment: It sounds like you have an empty vector and you're doing something like `v[0] = 1;` You need to either assign an initial size using that constructor or the `resize` function, or use the `push_back` function to add items to the end.

Comment: Your array has a fix size: `ptr = new int[grade_max];`. Btw. `int arr[grade_max]` had done the job as well because of the `const` in `const int grade_max`. However, you can do the same with a `std::vector`: `std::vector<int> vec(grade_max, 0);` (initializes the vector with size `grade_max` and fills all elements with 0).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie updated with my use of a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic mistake is that you try to force the vector as if it was a raw array. It does stuff for you, let it. It knows it's size, for instance. You don't need

```
void displayHistogram(int minGrade, vector<int> ptrV) {

    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= minGrade; i++) {
```

Instead, you can use `vector::size`:

```
void displayHistogram(vector<int> ptrV) {

    cout << endl;
    for (size_t i=0; i<ptrV.size(); i++) {
```

(Even better: `void displayHistogram(const vector<int>& ptrV)` to signify that ptrV is not changed here and to avoid copying it every time you call the function by using a reference.)

(If you wouldn't use the `i` as it is the grade and if you have a newer compiler, I'd recommend a for each loop instead. Those are usually the way to go, just happens that you have one of the rarer cases in which it isn't.)

Likewise, you first set the size of your vector and then increase it, which to me means that you do not trust it:

```
 vector<int> ptrV(grade_max, 0);
```

At this point, you have a vector with a hundred entries that are all zero. You don't need to resize it later if a hundred entries is all you need. `vector::push_back` resizes it. But note that setting it to a size of 100 means that [100] is not a valid position, the last one is [99], as we start to count at zero. You'd need to set it to a size of 101 to have both zero and hundred as valid addresses.

I'd change your code to:

```
const int grade_max = 100;
vector<int> ptrV(grade_max+1, 0); //changed it to +1 here as prtV[100] should be legal

cout << "Enter the student's grades (-1 to stop entering): \n";
while (true)
{
    int grade; // put stuff in the smallest scope possible
    cin >> grade;
    if(grade == -1) break; // doing that here means we don't have to think about it anymore - the do while does it at last, I do it at first, handling all the special cases at the start and then assume I have the regular case.
    if(grade < 0 or grade > grade_max) continue; // continue jumps to the top of the most inner loop. Note that I make sure to catch illegal but possible input.

    ptrV[grade] += 1; // personal preference, I use ++ only to iterate
}

displayHistogram(ptrV);
```

I rewrote the structure, using a `while(true)`, I think the way I did it is more intuitive, but there will be people who disagree with that and who would also write things like

```
if(grade == -1)
{
    break;
}
```

and there are some good arguments for that, mostly a good practice routine, always doing the braces to avoid errors. However, I prefer a one liner to reduce verbosity.

One improvement would also be to tell the user about bad input:

```
if(grade < 0 or grade > grade_max)
{
    cout << "Input not in valid range. Please choose number within 0 to " << grade_max << endl;
    continue;
}
```

Now, another big thing to do here would be to leave the procedural part, by the way.
Go for a `class GradeHistogram` which has all those functions as a part of it, being called like

```
GradeHistogram histogram;
histogram.take_input();
histogram.display();
```

but that is for when you get your code working.

(My answer became more of a review as found on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I think that this is what you need rather than small fixes. This is something I can only recommend you, by the way, putting your code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once it works.)

Comment: Thank you for your review & explaining each component. I've adjusted my code and it is not using the displayHistogram fx. correctly, but I will have to do some further adjustments. Perhaps I just need review what vectors have to offer. Cheers

Comment: @sethFrias For the start, it's mostly about understanding their constructor, `vector::size`, `vector::push_back` and `vector::resize`. Next step would be to learn the STL functions that work on such containers, like `std::sort` and `std::find`, plus maybe `erase` and `insert`. When you feel comfortable with those things, you might want to read into iterators of container classes, but that might be too much for the start. If you are interested about the inner workings of the class, consider `vector::reserve` and `vector::shrink_to_fit`, but those are not that easy.

Comment: @sethFrias Another thing to do for you is to get used to other container classes, such as `std::list`, `std::array` and `std::map`, and their advantages and disadvantages when compared to `vector`, including Big O notation (Bachmann-Landau-notation) applied on certain actions on those, like an insertion. In the end, it is about "the right tool for the right job".

Answer (score 1):

> but my goal is to store them in a vector.

The issue seems to be that you've already sized the vector to hold `grade_max` entries.  However when filling the vector, you are using `push_back`.  By using `push_back`, you are adding more entries to the end of the vector, which is not what you want to do.

The solution is either

1. Change this `vector<int> ptrV(grade_max, 0);` to this `vector<int> ptrV;` and leave the calls to `push_back` alone, or
2. Keep `vector<int> ptrV(grade_max, 0);` but instead merely use `ptrV[i] = grade;`

Comment: I tried this and changed my display loop to i < ptrV.size();, and I receive an output like:

Comment: changed my display loop to i < ptrV.size();, and I receive an output like: Number of 0's: 10, Number of 1's: 20,

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to show is a histogram, then the easiest thing to do would be to use a `std::map` from grade to count of grade.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter the student's grades (-1 to stop entering): \n";
    std::map<int, int> grades_map;
    int input_grade = -1;
    do {
        cin >> input_grade;
        if (input_grade > -1) {
            grades_map[input_grade]++;
        }
    } while (input_grade != -1);

    // Print histogram
    for (const auto& [grade, count] : grades_map) {
        std::cout << "Students with grade << grade << ": ";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            std::cout << '*';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```